# Can registration forms be used for an XSS attack?

Tags: web-application, xss

In most websites that have account logins, there are at least two fields:

- Email
- Password

Could either of these fields be used to mount an XSS attack (assuming no character encoding)?

For example, could this be submitted in the email field of a registration form:

```
<script src="www.example.com/mymaliciousscript.js"></script>newuser@stackexchange.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything originating from the client can be used for XSS: form fields (including hidden ones), query parameters, even cookies, User-Agent string, and HTTP headers.

Any field, no matter which one, printed back without sanitization is a potential vector for XSS.